# Convergence/divergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2k^3 -1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I was doing a homework question to determine whether this sequence diverges or not: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2k^3 -1}$$

Would I use the divergence test or the comparison test? Or is there another that is easier. My teacher did not really explain finding the limits of a geometric series so would I need to do that and if so how? I can't find any websites that have a straightforward method. Is L'Hopital's method a valid way of finding the limit?

Comment: At infinity, it has the behavior of the harmonic series

Answer (score 3):

Use the comparison test and you will see it diverges.
$\frac{k^2}{k^3-1}>\frac{k^2}{k^3}=\frac{1}{k}$

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution without inequalities: if we consider the "highest order terms" in the summand, note that for large enough $k$, we can estimate

$$ \frac{k^2}{2k^3 - 1} \sim \frac{1}{k} $$

because subtracting $1$ from a very large number doesn't really change its value. So, discarding the constant does not affect the limiting behavior. Now, the by limit comparison test, as $\sum \frac{1}{k}$ diverges, and

$$ \frac{k^2}{2k^3 - 1} \cdot \frac{k}{1} \to \frac{1}{2} $$

the original sum diverges.

Comment: Your argument is false. I don't have an example right away, but it can be easy enough to think of a sequence that sometimes greater than $\frac{k^2}{2k^3-1}$ and sometimes lower than it, and you'll get that the series of said sequence is convergent.

Comment: @ArielFishbein why is it wrong?